# Remove default "string" from swagger UI using .NET

Tags: .net, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle

Im using Swagger in .NET 5

After click on Try it out Swagger displays a "string" in the body. (Please see the below screenshot)

[image]
I want it to display "{}" instead.

That's what I tried:

```
public class EmptyStringRequestBodyFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var schema = operation.RequestBody?.Content?.FirstOrDefault().Value?.Schema;

            if (schema != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in schema.Properties)
                {
                    if (property.Value.Type == "string")
                    {
                        property.Value.Example = new OpenApiString("{}");
                        property.Value.Default = new OpenApiString("{}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and on Startup.cs :

```
 services.AddTransient<IOperationFilter, EmptyStringRequestBodyFilter>();
```

but it didn't help, I still get "string".

As I check how swagger generates by going to link  `http://localhost:<port>/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

I see this

```
"requestBody": {
  "content": {
    "application/json-patch+json": {
      "schema": { }
    },
```

Seems like it use some default value..

How can I replace to "{}" or just have empty?

Thx.

Comment: What does the controller/action in question look like?

Comment: Also, presumably, you are using swashbuckle.net, please confirm and provide the version you use. Or even better, provide a minimal repro, ideally on a supported version of .NET.

Comment: Can you search your codebase for this: `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions` - it makes all Controllers return a Json body. Currently your API returns a string because its returning Text not Json.

Comment: @Jermey I have this  services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(
                options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

Comment: For that you need to use the `SwaggerRequestBody` annotation I think => https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has been working for me:

```
 public class MyClassSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.Type == typeof(MyClass))
            {
                schema.Properties.Clear();
                schema.Type = "object";
            }
        }
    }
```

and on Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AAA", Version = "v1" });
                c.SchemaFilter<StartSessionSchemaFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In model:

```
public class HiModel
{
    [Required]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Hi{ get; set; }
}
```